# How to use client of my index in other files in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am currently working on a bot discord developed with Node.js.
I have correctly split my project by separating the different parts in associated folders.
[My project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y45ZM.png)
I have a problem though, because I need to use the client I created in the index in my guildMemberAdd.js and other files, but I don't know how to pass it correctly.
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxnhs.png)

I tried to put my client variable in global variable but it creates an error.
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzVTa.png)
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U98I.png)

Comment: Please, add your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass down the instantiated `client` to every file as it's available from the callback functions.

For example, if you want to get the `client` in the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event, you can grab it from the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=client) (which is the first parameter):

```js
// guildMemberAdd.js 
module.exports = {
  // ...
  async execute(member) {
    const { client } = member

    // you can use the client now :)
  }
}
```

It will work with other events too. Some examples below:

```js
// messageCreate.js
async execute(message) {
  const { client } = message
}
```

```js
// channelCreate.js
async execute(channel) {
  const { client } = channel
}
```

```js
// interactionCreate.js
async execute(interaction) {
  const { client } = interaction
}
```

If you still want to pass the `client`, you can pass it as the last parameter:

```js
for (const file of eventFiles) {
  const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
  const event = require(filePath);

  if (event.once) {
    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
  } else {
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
  }
}
```

This way `client` is the last argument:

```js
// guildMemberAdd.js 
module.exports = {
  // ...
  async execute(member, client) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, this way you will have to include every argument. For example, in `roleUpdate`:

```js
// roleUpdate.js 
module.exports = {
  // ⛔️ this won't work
  async execute(oldRole, client) {
    // client is a Role, not the Client
  
  // ✅ only this one will work
  async execute(oldRole, newRole, client) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to your index.js file to export the Client variable

```
module.exports = {client};
```

And then, you need to call the variable from the files that you want to use the variable in them using a destructor like this:

```
const {client} = require(relativePathOfIndexFile);
```